# mysql innoDb pages read per sec is increased all of a sudden

Tags: mysql, innodb, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I have been using cloudsql service (mySql 5.6) for almost 1 year without having any issues. Last 22nd April my database instance storage got auto increased and just after that the read performance is down.
In my database lots of daily transactions are recorded and there is a admin section where monthly reports can be viewed. While I am having no performance issue while writing to the database, admin report queries are taking above 30s to complete. Previously it took just a second or less.
I have checked the monitoring graphs, only innoDb read per sec is too high. After this incident I tried

1. cloning the instance, result:no performance improvement.
2. I tried creating a fresh new instance and dumped all the data from previous instance, Result: no performance improvement.

I am very much clueless. Here is a snapshot of my cloudsql overview.
[graph of cloudsql monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t3Cp.png)

========== Update ==========

I found another reason which might be causing the issue. Few days earlier I had to alter a table column from text to longtext. Now I am seeing that whenever I need to join that table the read time is higher, even if when I am not selecting that particular column.

Comment: Unless you're looking to optimise your code, in which case we'd need to see it, this is a question for [DBA.se]

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of the dataset (GB)?  What was the size before the slowdown?

What is the setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Since you have only 3.75GB of RAM, that setting should not be too high.

Those questions are simply to confirm the following:

The reports now require scanning lots of data.  In particular, the amount of data is more than can be held in cache (the buffer_pool).

The solution may be to build and maintain a Summary Table(s) for the reports.  This would eliminate the large number of page reads because the the table would be *incrementally* updated.  And it would make the reports run up to 10 times as fast.

Summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: my dataset size is 2.3 GB only. But I have found another reason which might be causing the issue. Few days earlier I had to alter a table column from text to longtext. Now I am seeing that whenever I need to join that table the read time is higher, even if when I am not selecting that particular column.

Comment: @JoyeshKarmakar - I still think you recently expanded the data past the buffer pool size _and_ the "report" reads too much data.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be some datatype changes to give you some temporary relief.  A Summary table is probably the optimal solution.